# Assembly Language: How to print string vertically?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to edit the traditional "Hello, world" program so that it prints vertically, such as:

H

e

l

l

o

,

w

o

r

l

d

!

I need to do this by using some sort of loop instructions, but I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong.

```
section .data
    text db "Hello, World!",10,0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, text
    call _print

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_print:
    push rax
    mov rbx, 0

_printLoop:
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]
    cmp cl, 0
    jne _printLoop

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    pop rsi
    mov rdx, rbx
    syscall

    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

The print syscall does not automatically append a newline, you will need to use a buffer where you can construct the new string. I've tried to keep most of your structure.

```
section .data
  text db `Hello, World!\n\0`

section .bss
  buffer resb 32

section .text
  global _start

_start:
  mov rax, text
  mov rbx, buffer
  call _print

  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall

_print:
  push rbx
  mov rdx, 0

_printLoop:
  mov byte [rbx], `\n`
  inc rbx
  mov cl, [rax]
  mov byte [rbx], cl
  inc rbx
  inc rax
  add rdx, 2
  cmp cl, 0
  jne _printLoop

  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  pop rsi
  syscall

  ret
```

In this function `rdx` is keeping track of the number of characters written, `rbx` points to the current character being written in the buffer and `rax` points to the current character being read from the source string.

As an aside:

- Rather than using `mov register, 0` prefers `xor register, register` unless changing flags would be problematic, it's an order of magnitude faster and smaller.
- Rather than using `cmp register, 0` use `test register, register`, it's faster and smaller.
- You have plenty of registers in x86-64 such r8, which you could use rather than the stack, which is much slower